# liquibase postgresql creating functions

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, liquibase

I am using liquibase to create triggers for postgressql database. Below is the syntax which I use in liquibase

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="yc14ik1">

        <createProcedure catalogName="cat" dbms="postgresql"
            encoding="utf8" procedureName="UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS()" relativeToChangelogFile="true" schemaName="sub">

            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS() RETURNS trigger
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $$
            BEGIN
                NEW.LAST_ROW_CHG_TS = NOW();
                RETURN NEW;
            END;
            $$;

        </createProcedure>


        <sql></sql>
</changeSet>
```

When this procedure is executed in Jenkins Job, I get this error

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: language "plpgsql" does not exist
  Hint: Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database. [Failed SQL: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS() RETURNS trigger
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $$
            BEGIN
                NEW.LAST_ROW_CHG_TS = NOW();
                RETURN NEW;
            END;
            $$;]


Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
```

Can some one help me how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I set up mine differently and it works just fine.

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
        <changeSet author="l" id="UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS" runOnChange="true">
                <createProcedure catalogName="UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS"
                        dbms="postgresql"
                        encoding="utf8"
                        path="../files/UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS.sql"
                        procedureName="UPDATE_LAST_ROW_CHG_TS"
                        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                        schemaName="public"></createProcedure>
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

from there you put all the sql inside a .sql file referenced in the path attribute.

I dont know that your way wont work but it seems odd to me that you have empty  tags towards the bottom. Maybe you meant for those to wrap your sql function?

Anyways I know the example above will work if liquibase is configured and ran properly.