# How to program with Liquibase XML files

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase, dbmigrate

I am used to DB programming with pure SQL files, but even if using an IDE, I am comfortable in seeing SQL commands like so as I can sit down with my developers and troubleshoot problems we encounter

```
create or replace function register_user (
    p_email                email_type,
    p_username             username_type,
    p_plain_text_password  plain_text_password_type
)
returns token_type
as $$
declare
    certificate token_type;
begin
    insert into user_account
    (
        email,
        username,
        encrypted_password
    )
    values
    (
        lower (p_email),
        lower (p_username),
        crypt (p_plain_text_password, gen_salt('bf'))
    );

    select into
        certificate get_user_account_activation_certificate (p_email := lower (p_email));

    return certificate;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

My devops team wants us to use a DB migration tool like [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) to help with automated deployments but Liquibase manages changes to the DB in XML like so (copied from [here](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/best-practices)). This is completely foreign to me. Imagine if GitHub demanded that you only write the changes to your code and then apply those changes incrementally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<databaseChangeLog   
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">   
  <changeSet  author="authorName"  id="changelog-1.0">  
    <createTable  tableName="TablesAndTables">  
      <column  name="COLUMN1"  type="TEXT">  
        <constraints  nullable="true"  primaryKey="false"  unique="false"/>  
      </column>  
    </createTable>  
  </changeSet>  
</databaseChangeLog>
```

To me, that XML approach is completely unacceptable and all my DB developers will resign if I force them to code like that. What are some better approaches to using Liquibase without completely blocking progress.

- Should I put the functions/procedures inside some sql file? (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577701/654789))
- Should I apply the changes incrementally (eg. create a blank function, then define its return value, then its parameters...)?
- Should we program the database alongside the migrations then convert the changes to XML and use that instead?
- Is there some GUI for Liquibase that will better manage these XML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase does not require that you use XML.  It works great with SQL too. You have a few options in how you structure things that are illustrated in the blogpost and the Liquibase documentation links below.

https://www.liquibase.org/blog/plain-sql

https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html